# Receiving the Nginx '404 Not Found' error after configuring the server block

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I installed nginx on my VPS, which runs Ubuntu 18.04. After setting up the DNS records for the domain to point to my VPS (just an A record pointing to the IP of the VPS), I still get a '404 Not Found' error, even though I believe my server block config is correct. I'll leave the config itself below, since there are kind people who have much more experience than me :)

P.S. I also included the changes that Certbot made since the site is using https, and the URL to the site in the config.

```
server {

        root /root/web/hudson/main;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name huds0n.xyz;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/huds0n.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/huds0n.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = huds0n.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



        server_name huds0n.xyz;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

[Image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1nH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain what you did with this configuration.

You defined two virtual servers. We drop the first one for now, let's explain the second one :

The first three lines of this server are the following :

```
    if ($host = huds0n.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

On the first line, we check if the $host variable given by nginx is `huds0n.xyz`. It is extracted from the `Host` request header from the HTTP Request.

If this is this host, we return a 301 HTTP Status code (Moved permanently) with the new location being `https://` + `$host` (The FQDN) + `$request_uri` (What's after the .xyz in our case).

We next define the server name which discriminates this server from the others. The combination Port + Server_name make nginx able to know which server configuration use when handling a request.

In this case, we're on HTTP unencrypted port, as seen on the next line with the host huds0n.xyz.

Even with this server name given to nginx, if you don't have a `default_server` indication in parameter of the `listen` directive, nginx might use this server to handle the request.

We next return a 404 Not Found error. Finally for this virtual server, we only get a 404 if we are not using the huds0n.xyz host. (Try for example, if you don't have anything else that prevents it to use the server IP in your browser to see if you're redirected).

Now, we have the first server block, which defines the SSL/TLS part of the server.

I see two issues with this configuration, but I will first explain what, for now, your configuration does.

You define the root location in the /root/web/hudson/main **folder**. It must be a folder.

So if you write in your browser `https://huds0n.xyz/i-like-bananas.html`, it will retrieve `i-like-bananas.html` in the main folder.

The following line is the index directive.
Let's imagine that in your main folder, you have a folder named `strawberry` and another one named `raspberry`. In `strawberry` you have a file named index.html containing a beautiful picture of a strawberry. In `raspberry`, unfortunately the webmaster forgot to put such a file.

With the index directive, you tell nginx to seek for the files (left to right order) given in the directive.
Nginx will, when you wrote the URL of a folder, seek index.html then if not found index.htm and so on.

Next block is a location block on the website root (`/`).
Every request made on this server is concerned by this block.

The try_files directive is similar to the index directive, but it is triggered by every URL, not only the URL associated to a folder.

It will try the URI (The right part of the URL after the host), then the URI as a folder or it will return a 404 error (Not found).

The next location block concerns every file that matches a regex (This is the tilde meaning), and this regex meaning is every filename that ends with `.php`.

For these files, we include some fastcgi php configuration, which will provide PHP the needed variables for handling the request, and we pass the request and the variables to the unix socket located in `/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`.

After, we have the directive that make nginx listen on HTTPS port, and the SSL/TLS configuration. I'll skip this part.

The two issues I mentionned before are the following :

- You want to use PHP, but your index directive points on HTML files. If you want index.php to be used for your root webpage, change it to `index index.php`
- In your location `/` block, you try the $uri, the $uri plus a slash, then you return a 404. Many CMS/Framework (I'm thinking to laravel for example) make possible a kind of rewrite of the URL. You have one PHP file (index.php for example) which handles **every** request. How does it work ? We simply give PHP the path info as a `filename + path` in a FastCGI variable.
  You can change your block to fill this mission by putting this instead of your `try_files` directive :  `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

The root cause of this 404 may also be the fact that your nginx server cannot access the folder, or that your folder is missing/empty.

As originally designed, your web content SHOULD be in the `/var/www/<subfolder>` folder, and be owned by `www-data`.

You should not put your files in the /root folder.

I hope this will answer your question, and help you to find a cause to your issue.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I have one more question. Is it possible to use both files with '.html' and '.php' in the same directory?

Comment: Yes of course, but you need to request them with the URL.

You might also want to use it as index files. Writing `index index.php index.html` will make nginx seek a PHP file then a HTML file.